# ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: jax-rs, integration-testing, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

When I tested a restful web service inside the latest jdeveloper 12c with integrated weblogic 12c, I got the error in messages-log tab :

```
[11564:14496:0105/092028.519:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

This issue hasn't block my working. But during testing chrome got into an invalid state. How to suspend or block or repair this problem?

OS: MSWin10En64bit Enterprise